# Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write create function for my multi-level serializer but getting this error. Here's my code -

I have **Models.py**

```
class Zorg(models.Model):

    name               = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner_first_name   = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    owner_last_name    = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    zorg_email_id     = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    owner_email_id     = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    open_year_of_zorg = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    website            = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    base_rating        = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    joined             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Categories(models.Model):
    zorg = models.ForeignKey(Zorg, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='categories')
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name  + ' - ' + str(self.zorg) 


class Service(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, related_name="services")
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.service_name + ' in ' + str(self.category)
```

Here's my **serializer.py**

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        exclude = ['id', 'category']

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    services = ServiceSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Categories
        fields = ['category_name', 'services']

class ZorgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Zorg
        fields = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'owner_first_name',
        'owner_last_name',
        'zorg_email_id',
        'owner_email_id',
        'open_year_of_zorg',
        'website',
        'base_rating',
        'categories',
        ]
    def create(self, validated_data):
        categories = validated_data.pop('categories')
        zorg = Zorg.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for category in categories:
            Categories.objects.create(zorg=zorg, **category)
            services = category.pop('services')
            for service in services:
                Service.objects.create(category=category, **service)
    return zorg
```

I am trying to write .create function for it but I am unable to write the proper create function for the zorg serializer.
GET is working just fine and I am getting expected results but POST and PUT is where I am having trouble with multi level depth.

This is how I want to pass my data in the JSON format.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sample",
    "owner_first_name": "Sample",
    "owner_last_name": "Sample",
    "salon_email_id": "sample@mail.com",
    "owner_email_id": "samplee@mail.com",
    "open_year_of_zorg": "2014",
    "website": "http://sample.in",
    "base_rating": 2,
    "categories": [
        {
            "category_name": "Sample Category",
            "services": [
                {
                    "service_name": "Sample Service",
                    "time": 30,
                    "price": "300.00"
                },
                {
                    "service_name": "Sample Service",
                    "time": 0,
                    "price": "100.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "category_name": "Sample Category 2",
            "services": [
                {
                    "service_name": "Sample Service 2",
                    "time": 50,
                    "price": "600.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error I am getting -
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create(self, validated_data):          
        categories = validated_data.pop('categories')
        zorg = Zorg.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for category in categories:
            services = category.pop('services')
            category = Categories.objects.create(zorg=zorg, **category)
            
            for service in services:
                Service.objects.create(category=category, **service)
        return zorg
```